# More than one Activity running at once on android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Can I have an activity running in the background while another activity is running?

Comment: Yes, you can please go through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) then

[Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components)

> A service is a component that runs in the background to perform
>   long-running operations or to perform work for remote processes. A
>   service does not provide a user interface. For example, a service
>   might play music in the background while the user is in a different
>   application, or it might fetch data over the network without blocking
>   user interaction with an activity. Another component, such as an
>   activity, can start the service and let it run or bind to it in order
>   to interact with it.